# What is the equivalent of app.config in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, configuration

I have only few projects on my bag. In a previous desktop application when I wanted to store and use some application specific information I was using the `app.config` file.

Now I work on `ASP.NET MVC 4` application and again I want to store some application specific information but this time I'm not sure. I have the `web.config` file which seems like a good place for this purpose but I'm not sure if it's the right place to store custom information there.

What is the right approach to do this? For example I want to save and extract path to directory on the file system where I'll save all my files. In `ASP.NET MVC 4` what/where is the right place to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `web.config` file is what web application use where a desktop application uses `app.config`, and it's a good place to put application specific information.

You can add keys to the `<appSettings>` tag, and use them in the application just as you would if you put them in that tag in the `app.config` file. Example:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataPath"];
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems much like in a Desktop app. Gonna use it!

Answer (score 3):

`Web.config` is for ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC; `app.config` is for desktop applications and DLLs.

If you need to storie any kind of parameter for your application that you can change without having to recompile, `Web.config` is the place to go.

Comment: Yeah, to change without recompile is only one of the things, what worries me is that all configuration data goes to the same place - `Web.config` and even though for my specific case it may not be an issue since I won't have much to put in there, I thought that there is maybe another approach due to the fact the the configuration list my become a long one.

Comment: If it's configuration and not data, it belongs in a config file, even if it's a lot of configuration. But you can also chop up config files using a `configSource` attribute, as shown here: http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/16/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Web.config is the web application version of app.config. Web.config seem like a good place for the configuration settings you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you have a dll that had reference to desktop app.config, and when you import that MVC application you need to change the configuration data that used to be in app.config now to web.config.